# How to set up dual power sources for e-bike motor?

Tags: power, batteries, diodes

trying to set up a power system for my ebike with both battery power and man power through crank.  pls see chart attached. The battery voltage is 48v.  The man power through the crank is 10 to 48v. 
 Do i need a regulator to keep the man power voltage to 48v via a voltage regulator?  Can i use 2 10A diode as a 20A diode ? thank you so much[image]

Comment: Use proper punctuation and grammar, you could also take the time and format the question so its readable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/277593/multiple-power-source-and-diode-protection

Comment: Using diodes as shown, the motor will receive no power from the crank as long as it is providing less voltage than the battery.

Comment: Man power should drive the bike directly, not through generating electrical power. Motors & generators run about 80% efficiency, so mechanical to electrical 80%, then electrical back to mechanical 80% (.8 x .8 = .56 = 56% after conversions).

Comment: Voltage is proportional to RPM, pedal to battery Power is proportional to excess Torque * RPM ( if you have any excess ) which must exceed battery voltage  ( i.e. threshold Speed)

Comment: You will need a speed control. Without it there is always full power from the battery to the DC motor, it would be very dangerous to drive that bike. Buy an e-bike at a shop but forget to build one by yourself.

Comment: @Optionparty: You need to brush up on your math skills.

Comment: @Uwe: Which part of "controller" (the box between the battery and the motor) is confusing you?

Comment: @laptop2d: That other question discusses another way to do the diode ORing, but does not address the rest of this question at all.

Comment: @Dave Tweed: The missing word "speed".

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you don't need a regulator since the motor will have a wide range of voltage capability.

More critical is whether you can use two 10 A diodes in parallel to create a 20 A capability. 
The short answer is maybe.
You'd need to provide the actual diode type to make a real determination.

If you have two of the same diodes (make/component) then they will work in parallel, but you cannot guarantee that they will share the forward current between them equally. There will be slight variation in the Vf and temperature for the two diodes so if for example their **absolute maximum** continuous forward current was 10 A, any imbalance at 20 A total would result in one diode being stressed beyond its ratings.

Could/would this make a difference in your application?
I'd seriously doubt it and would suggest you'd be quite OK using two parallel 10 A continuous rated (not absolute maximum) diodes of the same type.
It would seem unlikely that you would actually get close to 20 A (20 A @ 48 V = 960 W, and I doubt your motor is near that powerful) for more than a few seconds so 20 A seems more like a peak current.

If your average current through the diodes is well less than the individual diode current capability, then any imbalance will be quite insignificant. You should however make sure you use the same diode make/component.